# JQuery Mobile right to left css

Tags: css, jquery-mobile

I'm reading now about jquery mobile UI.
Their css if left to right, Someone know where I can download a right to left css?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you would have to do this yourself, here is the theming docs: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/#docs/api/themes.html but I think if you wanted custom CSS you will have to write it yourself

Answer (score 14):

I made an RTL version of it here: [jQuery Mobile RTL](http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl)

Comment: I saw your work, and it's very impressive. I understand that need to change float and text-align. Could you explain what you did ?

Comment: @moutaz-shams awesome work! any release date plans for jqm 1.4.5?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a guide if you want to convert any JQM to rtl.

> 1. Add a direction attribute with “rtl” value to the body CSS
> 2. Overwrite all css classes that has “float:right” with “float:left” and vise
>      versa
> 3. Overwrite all css classes that has “left:” with “right:” and
>      vise versa. It is worth mentioning her that you keep the previous
>      attribute and make it auto. Else it won’t work. i.e. left:15px
>      should be overwrite with left:auto;right:15px.
> 4. Do the same as point 3 for all classes that has margin-left, margin-right, padding-left and padding-right

Also change all text-align from left to right and vise versa.

Source: http://abuhijleh.net/2012/07/01/guide-right-to-left-languages-support-for-jquery-mobile/

Answer (score 0):

Put this line in HEAD tag

```
 <style>body {direction:rtl}</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made an RTL version of **jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css** I called it **jquery.mobile-1.4.5_rtl.css** you can download it from [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/49907374/jquery.mobile-1.4.5_rtl.rar).
Please note that you still might need to modify it if you want to change [icons](https://api.jquerymobile.com/icons/). I changed only the icon carat-r to carat-l and vise versa.

Enjoy!

Comment: Hi, the link is not working, can you please update it? Thanks a lot

Comment: You can download it from [here](https://github.com/rafraph/jquery.mobile-1.4.5_rtl.css/blob/master/jquery.mobile-1.4.5_rtl.css)